# What is the actual usecase of trylock in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, locking

What is the actual usecase of trylock in java.
If I check trylock in if block and write an else block, I will end up loosing actual business logic which is there in if block and thread will never hit the if block again.
I am wondering what could be actual business usecase for this.

I am trying to use reentrantLock.tryLock()

Comment: I don't recall a usecase rightnow, but `trylock` returns immediately (or specified time period if 2nd signature is used) with true/false based on whether a lock was acquired or not. If in your design the same thread that has to do something critical and something that is not critical without importance of order. Then you can put this in a loop, whenever a lock is acruired do critical thing & then release lock, else do non-critical thing. And keep doing that again and again. If your thread does not have anything non-critical, then you can just use `lock`.

Comment: Say you don't want to make the user wait for getting a lock and then do the operation, but tell the user that something else is going on right now, cannot do the operation that you asked for.  In this case, you can use trylock - if it returns true, do the operation, release the lock and tell the user that it is done. If it returns false, tell the user, you cannot do it right now, something else is going on.

Comment: If in above case, you don't use tryLock, and use `lock` and keep waiting for an indefinite time, because the other operation might take hours - that is not good.

Comment: “…and thread will never hit the if block again” Java has loops, among other tools to repeat an action. But don’t try to find a use case for an existing feature. Once you encounter a scenario where this would be helpful, you will automatically start searching for the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual use case of `tryLock()` in Java is to acquire the lock only if it is available at the time of invocation. This is useful in scenarios where you don't want the thread to wait forever for the lock. If the lock is not available, the thread can perform some other tasks instead of waiting. The `tryLock()` method returns a boolean value indicating whether the lock was acquired or not, which can be used in an if-else block to decide what to do next.

In your case, if the business logic in the if block is important and must be executed, you should not use `tryLock()`. Instead, use `lock()` which makes the thread wait until the lock is available.

Example use case: you have a time consuming process which is executed in worker thread, which is executed under a lock. You need to finish your application, and to gracefully finish worker process you will have to wait for its lock release. To do it you will set a flag informing the process that it should finish as soon as possible, and also will periodically call tryLock on its lock to check if it is actually finished (tryLock would return true then). In your `if(!lock.tryLock()) {` block you can log the reason for the delay, you can add short sleep to not hog the CPU. As Mark Rotteveel suggested, using `tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)` would be best here. If the closing time is too long you can take actions to finish the worker process less gracefully.

Comment: Your example would be better served by using [`tryLock(long, TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) instead of `tryLock()`.

Answer (score 2):

> [...the] thread will never hit the if block again...

Sounds like maybe *you* have no immediate use for `tryLock`. But, in someone else's code;

1. The thread might try the lock in a loop, and
2. The lock might only be lightly contested (i.e., there's only a low probability that the `tryLock()` call will fail,) and finally,
3. The need to access the shared variables might not be urgent. Perhaps that access always can be deferred until a later iteration of the loop.

If all of those things are true, then `tryLock` makes it possible to defer the shared access, and keep the loop running on a regular schedule.